# How the type `Fix` and function `fix` are same in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fixpoint-combinators

I'm trying to convince myself that type `Fix` and function `fix` are the same thing.
But I can't find the correlation between their definitions

```hs
-- definition of fix 
fix :: (p -> p) -> p
fix f = let {x = f x} in x -- or fix f = f (fix f)
-- definition of Fix
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
```

How does the constructor `Fix` fit into the form of `(x -> x) -> x`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the kind of the type constructor `Fix`:

```
> :k Fix
Fix :: (* -> *) -> *
```

The *type* constructor `Fix` is what's analogous to the function `fix`.

The *data* constructor is something else. Following the explanation found in [Understanding F-Algebras](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras), `Fix` is an *evaluator*: it evaluates a term of type `f (Fix f)` to produce a value of type `Fix f`. This evaluation is *lossless*; you can recover the original value from the result using `unFix`.

Comment: I'm hoping the last paragraph is both sensible and correct.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take the naive implementation of `fix`:

```hs
fix f = f (fix f)
```

For a function `f`, this creates something like the following:

```hs
f (f (f (f (f (f (f ...
```

The `Fix` newtype does the same, but for types. So if we take the type `Maybe`, we would want to create:

```hs
Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe ...
```

How would we create a function which constructs that type? We can first try with a type synonym:

```hs
--   fix f = f (fix f)
type Fix f = f (Fix f)
```

You should be able to see that this is the same as the naive implementation of `fix` above with some minor changes. But it's not legal Haskell!

This is for a number of reasons: mainly, Haskell doesn't allow infinite types like the `Maybe` example above, and Haskell's type system is strict, in contrast to the lazy evaluation required in `fix`. That's why we need a `newtype`. New type definitions (introduced with `newtype` or `data`) allow recursion, so we take our type synonym and change it into a newtype.

```hs
type    Fix f =                f (Fix f)
newtype Fix f =                f (Fix f)   -- change to newtype
newtype Fix f = Fix           (f (Fix f))  -- need to have a constructor
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) } -- And name the field, also
```